# How do I prevent Duplicate Class error while using same named class in different flavors?

Tags: android, gradle, android-productflavors

First of all, I have just checked a lot of topics in StackOverflow about this issue but none of them solved my problem. My problem is; I have 2 different flavors which are main and experimental named flavors. ***main*** is default flavor. I just want to override or use my A.java in experimental build variant but this causes me duplicate class found an error. How can I prevent or fix this issue because I believe that using same named class can be possible via flavors? Or did I do something wrong? I hope you can help me with my problem. Thanks in advance.

**Project Structure**

- app

  - src

    - main

      - java

        - core

          - A.java
    - experimental

      - java

        - core

          - A.java

**build.gradle**

`productFlavors{
    main{
        dimension = "default"
        applicationId "com.example.yekta.basicApp.main"
    }
    experimental{
        dimension = "default"
        applicationId "com.example.yekta.basicApp.experimental"
    }
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
        res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets']
    }

    experimental {
        java.srcDirs = ['src/experimental/java']
        res.srcDirs = ['src/experimental/res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['src/experimental/assets']
    }
}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Step #1: Rename your one flavor from `main` to any other valid value that is not `main`, `test`, or `androidTest` (or, in your case, `experimental`, since you already have a flavor by that name)

Step #2: Set up a source set for your newly-renamed flavor, using the name that you chose from Step #1

Step #3: Move your `A.java` from `main` to the source set that you created in Step #2

The `main` source set is for code that will be used across all product flavors and build types. You cannot change that by attempting to turn `main` into a product flavor.

Note that on Android Studio 3.2, it appears that attempting to define a product flavor named `main` results in a build crash — at least, it is crashing when I tried reproducing this problem.

Comment: I renamed that flavour to experimentalTwo but still it says; Duplicate class found in the file {which is in main directory of that A.class file}. Now, I have three A.java in the project. First one is under experimental directory. Second one is under experimentalTwo directory and the last one is in the main directory.

Comment: @YektaSarıoğlu:  There cannot be an `A.java` in `main` -- all implementations must be in product flavors (and each product flavor needs an implementation). That is why I suggested that you move `A.java` from `main` to the new source set.

Comment: I missed that part. Now, it works. Thank you for your help, @CommonsWare